# Textbox change stopping button click in Jquery

Tags: jquery, button, textbox

I am having a strange behavior with a textbox

I am having a textbox and button on page both of them have change and click event respectively. Both even work individually, but when I click the button after changing the value on textbox the click event does not fire.

```
$("#txtInput").on("blur", function onChange() {
    var randomVal = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    $('#log').append('<p>New value: ' + randomVal + '</p>');
    return true;
});


$("#btn-submit").on("click", function submit() {
    alert('value submitted');
});
```

Help me understand this.

Here is a link for the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/25/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the button above the result div. Because, blur event happens before the button click event, which results in the movement of button downwards.(For a click event to be fired, both mouse down and mouse up happens on the same element.) That is why it is not fired.

```
<p>Enter something</p>
<input type="text" id="txtInput">
<button value="Go" style="display:block" type="button" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
<div id="log"></div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/27/)

Comment: I have updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/30/, when doing an alert on textbox change then also button click fire stops. why?.

Comment: it will still have the same problem again, mouse down and up events are not happening on the button. use console.log instead https://jsfiddle.net/WV3Q8/31/